# Apply EnvoyFilter for specific routes or paths

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I would like to use EnvoyFilter in Istio to specify behavior for specific routes or paths.

For example if the Pod has multiple access paths like /foo and /bar,
denies access to /foo and responds with status 500, but allows access to /bar.

I only know how to block all access to a specific Pod using workloadSelector as shown below:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: block-all
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: { some-pods-label }
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.router"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
       name: envoy.lua
       typed_config:
         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
         inlineCode: |
           function envoy_on_request(handle)
             handle:respond({[":status"] = "500"})
           end
```

Is there a better way than write conditional statements for all paths in a lua script?

Or is there a way to use the VirtualService's metadata to determine whether to apply EnvoyFilter or not?

Comment: From what I understood from you question you would like to deny request that comes to specific path.  To me seems like this can be achieved using [authroization policy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/). Is this is something that you want?

Comment: It seems that the authentication policy can be used only when all paths are known.
I think this method is inefficient compared to Traefik's middleware.